# Overflow text when i'm Fill text in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a long string that has spaces. My source code:

Code:

```
<canvas id="text_1"  ></canvas>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(function(){
            var ctx= document.getElementById("text_1").getContext("2d");
            ctx.canvas.width  =  136;
            ctx.canvas.height =  30;
            ctx.font="10px Times New Roman";
            ctx.fillText("PHAT TRIEN PHAN MEM HUONG DOI TUONG VA RAT NHIEU CHU RAT LA DAI O DANG SAU NUA",0,10);
            ctx.textAlign = 'left';
            ctx. textBaseline = 'left';
            ctx.beginPath();
            canvas_arrow(ctx,10,10,100,10);         
    });
    </script>
```

When it run , my canvas display look this:

```
-----------------------
|    PHAT TRIEN PHAN  |             |
-----------------------
```

And i need look look like

```
---------------------------
|    PHAT TRIEN PHAN MEM  |
|    HUONG DOI TUONG VA   |
|    RAT NHIEU CHU RAT    |
|    LA DAI O DANG SAU NUA|
|                         |
---------------------------
```

Please help me!!!!!

Comment: please can u provide a fiddle example

Comment: Look at this if it can help you. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/

Comment: @markE i'm sorry about this. I'll fix that next time. Thank you for prompt!